# How can I write a typeguard that recognizes whether something is a Type<T>?

Tags: angular, typescript, typeguards

I've got a type definition that allows for various ways of supplying an object:

`type ObjSource<T> = InjectionToken<T> | Type<T> | ((context: IContext) => (T | Promise<T>)) | Promise<T> | T;`

In there, `IContext` is an interface of my own that provides some context information about (a part of) my application.

To properly evaluate all of these, I need to find out what object source was actually supplied. I'm trying to do so with custom type guard functions. Let's start:

- If the value is of type `InjectionToken<T>` or `Type<T>`, I'd simply like to stuff it into Angular's [`inject` function](https://angular.io/api/core/inject), thereby letting Angular's dependency injection deal with it.
- If the value is of type `((context: IContext) => (T | Promise<T>))`, I'd like to execute that function and pass the result to [`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve).
- Otherwise, i.e. if the value is of type `Promise<T>` or `T`, I'd like to pass it to [`Promise.resolve`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve).

Now, how can I distinguish these cases?

- I think I can recognize an `InjectionToken<T>` by virtue of it being an instance of the [`InjectionToken` class](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken):

  ```js
  function isInjectionToken<T>(x: ObjSource<T>): x is InjectionToken<T> {
    return x instanceof InjectionToken;
  }
  ```
- I know next to nothing about `T`. I *might* be able to restrict it to `T extends object`. In that case, I distinguish `(context: IContext) => (T | Promise<T>)` from `Promise<T> | T` by the fact that `typeof` returns `function` for the former, but not the latter.

But **how do I distinguish `Type<T>` from `(context: IContext) => (T | Promise<T>)`?**

[Angular's `Type<T>`](https://angular.io/api/core/Type) is defined as:

```js
class Type<T> extends Function {
  constructor(...args: any[]): T
}
```

Using a tiny sample Angular app, I've tried various implementations for `isType<T>(x: ProviderToken<T>): x is Type<T>` in here:

```js
export class App {
  public doClick() {
    const a = isType(function blah() {
      return true;
    });
    const b = isType(new InjectionToken<string>('xyz'));
    const c = isType(App);

    alert(`${a} ${b} ${c}`);
  }
}
```

So far, though, I have not been able to find the right criteria to check:

- `x instanceof Type` returns `true` for the third, but also the first case.
- `typeof x === 'function'` (unsurprisingly) returns `true` for the first and the third case, as well.
- `typeof x === 'function' && Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(x, 'constructor')`, on the other hand, returns `false` in all cases.

Comment: (Caveat: I don't use Angular) If `Type<T>` is as shown above (it's `interface Type extends Function { }` in `angular-component-router.d.ts` in `@types/angular`, but that's close enough), I don't think you can (reasonably) distinguish it from your `(context: IContext) => (T | Promise<T>)`. Both are functions, and at runtime there's very little you can know about a function; basically just its `name` (if it has one) and `length`, neither of which are useful to you. (You could try to play `toString` tricks, but it's fairly ugly.) From a type perspective, your function is a `Type<T>`, as well. :-|

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: The compiler clearly knows the difference between a type and a function (e.g. I can assign `App` to a variable of type `Type<any>`, but I cannot assign `function blah() { return x; }` to that variable). It's a pity it doesn't store that information somewhere that is accessible at runtime.

Comment: "It's a pity it doesn't store that information somewhere that is accessible at runtime" Emitting JS that knows about TS types is explicitly a [non-goal of TypeScript (#5)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) so that's not going to happen. If you want runtime information you should add it and then, depending on they way you that, TS will also know about it.  I'd suggest something more concrete but I am also no Angular expert so I'll defer to those who are.

Comment: @F-H - I was looking at the wrong package, `Type` in `@angular/core` is (roughly) defined the way the linked docs say (the definition shown in the docs is conceptual [technically invalid TypeScript -- constructors can't have a return type annotation -- but the actual definition is an interface with a construction *signature*, which can]). Any constructor function is a valid `Type<T>` (`Date`, for example, or `Map`), but not your `IContext` functions. But runtime, yeah, it's a `toString` game if you really need to tell those apart without doing something to brand your `IContext` functions.